# Approaches to analyzing data from forum

Tags: descriptive-statistics, multilevel-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis, sentiment-analysis

Working with self written example data that mimic a chat-forum with different forums (i.e. cars, politics, sports) and different threads (i.e. "why is porsche popular?", "thoughts on andrew yang?") in R, I have been really interested in text-analytics, lately, and have tried a number of tools which allow sentiment analysis (LIWC, syuzhet, BAWL-R), based on simple lexical-matching approaches, and have also encountered machine-learning approaches, but wasn't able to implement them, yet. Ignoring the fact that these lexical approaches face many problems in the real world, I now asked myself, when analyzing larger data-sets, which statistical tools could one use to gain knowledge about the processes involved in different chats? The first thing I was thinking of was multilevel-regression to predict the length of a thread, for example from valence (neg. and pos. valence of post), but I think the relationship between valence and length of a thread would be more complex.

Hoping that I don't upset anyone with the general character of my question, I now wanted to ask, what other statistical methods come to mind when working with such data? Is there any way to look at the relationship between posts following each other (i.e. predicting valence of the post after from the post before), or are there any other questions that arise, that I haven't looked at? Again, I know that my question is really broad and I do not expect exact answer, but am rather looking for inspiration and material to look at, also since I didn't get any training on this matter as a physics undergrad.

Thanks for any thoughts and recommendations.

---

Edit: If this is the wrong forum for this type of question or if a question like this is off limits, also please let me know, since this is my first post in this forum.

Comment: I think that actually this is the wrong forum for this kind of questions, which are considered "too broad"

Comment: @carlo Do you know if there’s one where this question would be right?

Comment: not sure, probably on some sub-reddit. most internet communities are very much centered on ML though

Comment: Thanks, I'll look. This is not about ML vs. lexical-based, though, but rather about what one can do with data obtained by either method.

Comment: I am voting to leave this open. "Too broad" means (per the guideline) having not "enough detail to identify an adequate answer".  Here, an "adequate answer" seems like it could be a list of methods rather than a whole set of worked out solutions.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica Thanks. Do you have any ideas on the question?

Comment: @Markus No, sorry. Text analytics is not something I do.

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica But aside from text-analytics, how about a method regarding a nested time series with interval scales?